# Regex - get only last upper letter

Tags: regex

i try to get only upper letter in the last of this sentence

```
abc N°12558 to company ABC DEF GH 123
```

i want take only ABC DEF GH

i try this, but number in last make problem

```
(.[A-Z\s]+)*$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```sh
\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*(?=[^A-Z]*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K1EFFA/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `[A-Z]+`: Match a word with 1+ uppercase letters
- `(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*`: Match 0 or more space separated uppercase words
- `(?=[^A-Z]*$)`: Lookahead to assert that we don't have any uppercase letters ahead

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps you: https://regex101.com/r/RtcacF/1

This regex will only match the upper case letters (1 or more) that are followed with a space or tab.

```
[A-Z]+\s
```

if you don't want to keep the space you can wrap it with a group, like this:

```
([A-Z]+)\s
```

https://regex101.com/r/RtcacF/2